# Jquery disable submit button if submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to disable the submit button once I have click "Submit and Email". That means the submit button should not be clickable after the user clicked "Submit and Email". I have updated the answer based on feedback.

```
; (function ($) {

    $.fn.tpFormDialogCustom = function (method) {

        var self = this;

        var dialogButtons = [
          {
              text: "Submit and Email",
              id: "tpFormDialog_btnSubmit",
              click: submitandmailTpFormDialog
          },


function submitandmailTpFormDialog() {
  if(CheckValidate()) {
    commonDialogs.showError(ExampleMessages.JournalError);
  } else {
    commonDialogs.showConfirm(ExampleMessages.ConfirmEmail, function() {
      try {
        commonDialogs.showProgress(ExampleMessages.SubmitAndEmail);
        var o = getOptions();
        var form = $(o.form);
        form.ajaxSubmit({
          success: handleEmailResponse,
          beforeSerialize: function($form, options) {
            if(!$("#SubmitBtn", $form).length) {
              $('select.required', $form).prop('disabled', false);
              $form.append("<input id='SubmitBtn' type='hidden' name='From' value='Submit' />");
            }
          }
        });
      } catch(e) {
        commonDialogs.showError();
      }
    });
  }
}


function handleEmailResponse(data) {
            $('#tpFormDialog_btnSubmit').prop("disabled", true);
            commonDialogs.hideProgress();
            var o = getOptions();
            if (data.IsSuccess) {
                commonDialogs.showAck(ExampleMessages.ConfirmSendEmail);
                closeTpFormDialog();
                o.table.refresh();
            } else {
                var errors = data.ResponseModel;
                if (typeof (errors) === 'string') {
                    commonDialogs.showError(errors);
                } else {
                    helpForValidation.showErrors(errors);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Have you tried simply unbinding the click element in your submit function? Using either `.unbind()` or `.off()`. Also, when you pick by ID in this line: `$('tpFormDialog_btnSubmit').prop("disabled", true)` you want to use # - i.e. '#tpFormDialog_btnSubmit'. It won't pick it otherwise.

Comment: What's the question? Does it work? If not, why not? Any errors?

Comment: No it doesn't work. No errors. I just want the button to disable (unclickable) after user click submit.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code for the disbale the button is :

```
function handleEmailResponse(data) {
            $('#tpFormDialog_btnSubmit').prop("disabled", true);
            commonDialogs.hideProgress();
            var o = getOptions();
            if (data.IsSuccess) {
                commonDialogs.showAck(ExampleMessages.ConfirmSendEmail);
                closeTpFormDialog();
                o.table.refresh();
            } else {
                var errors = data.ResponseModel;
                if (typeof (errors) === 'string') {
                    commonDialogs.showError(errors);
                } else {
                    helpForValidation.showErrors(errors);
                }
            }
        };
```

You are missing '#' (id selector) in the `$('tpFormDialog_btnSubmit').prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: @user3807187 you want to disbale button after click of after success ?

Comment: I want to disable button after success.

Comment: @user3807187 can you html of your button ?

Comment: There is no html of my button. Im using  var dialogButtons = [
          {
              text: "Submit and Email",
              id: "tpFormDialog_btnSubmit",
              disabled: "disabled",
              click: submitandmailTpFormDialog
          },

Comment: that i already check, can you inspect through developer tool and capture the html and show me here ?

Comment: <span class="ui-button-text">Submit and Email</span>

Comment: <button type="button" id="tpFormDialog_btnSubmit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Submit and Email</span></button>